# HTML Styling code not working in JSP file

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, jsp

I am using Eclipse Kepler to create a web application and and trying to get my jsp files designed before starting my functionality. When I create the following code as a basic html file, it can be opened in the browser with perfect design. But when I write this code in a jsp file with the additional

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

as the first two lines, the file loses all of its positional styling. If you run the code in a jsp, you will notice that bordering and link coloration remain the same, but everything is positioned in the same spot.

Any one know how to deal with this? Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>

<style>
body {
background-image: url(Images/whitebg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

#container {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header img {
position: absolute;
top: 80;
left: 72;
width: 200;
height: 50;
}

#container a:visited {
color: blue;
}

#container a:hover {
color: red;
}

#welcome {
position: absolute;
top: 20;
right: 100;
}

#logout {
position: absolute;
top: 20;
right: 20;
width: 50px;
height:25px;
}

#links {
position: absolute;
top: 200;
left: 72;
}

#links ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5 10 5 10;
border: 2px solid red;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#links li {
padding: 10 0 25 0;
}

#feed {
position: absolute;
top: 100;
left: 400;
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
}

#feedtext {
width:800px;
height:400px;
overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id='container'>

<div id='header'>
    <img src='Images/mPowerlogo.jpg'/>
</div>

<div id='welcome'>
    Welcome, User1
</div>

<div id='logout'>
    <a href=''>Logout</a>
</div>

<div id='links'>
    <ul>
    <li><a href=''>Timecard Management</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>User Management</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Customer Management</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id='feed'>
    <p>Recent Activity:</p>
    <textarea id='feedtext' readonly>

    </textarea>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you see if you inspect the elements with the Elements Inspector from Google Chrome (F12)???

Comment: I don't know asp, but is it anything to do with `language='java'`?

Answer (score 2):

Change positions other than 0 to have glued to it "px".

```
top: 20px;
```

Or remove the DOCTYPE as that requires the HTML/CSS to be considered correct (though it is not).

***Tip:***
Also you might consider using "Windows-1252" in Java. The browsers will interprete ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252 (even on Mac and Linux). And some special characters like comma-like quotes that MS Word so likes, will be present. HTML-5 makes this hidden functonality an official specification.

Comment: god catch on px, so in first version it just works in some quircks mode, but it will not work in html 5, 4 or any other "correct" mode, BTW: I did not see that answer when writing my version

Comment: Wait, where am I adding these 20px? My container margin?

Comment: or do you simply mean all positional pixel statements require "px" after it?

Comment: I understand what you wrote now. That worked. I was confused because not having "px" would work if I called that style from a servlet and it worked as a basic html, so I figured it had to be something else. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the line `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` you are changing the html version from something that will be probably parsed as 5 (without doctype, you end up using some kind of quirks mode, wchich even works with your style that is missing px) to 4.01 Transitional. And that's what happen, when you do that. Different version - different results.

You have to decide which version do you want to use (if html 5 - then use `<!DOCTYPE html>`). Also I suggest using UTF not the 8859-1 (but that is an option).

Try changing encoding in that line `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>`.

Comment: I simply changed <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> to <!DOCTYPE html> and it did not change anything. When changing the encoding, do you mean replacing every "ISO-8859-1" with "UTF-8" or "UTF" or whatever it would be?

Comment: @DanMcNamara please see the Joop Eggen answer, he is right, that the main problem is the incorrect style - the missing px